# Show that for all integers $k \ge 2$ every graph $G$ contains a $k$-partite subgraph $H$ with $e(H) \ge \frac{k-1}{k}e(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Show that for all integers $k \ge 2$ every graph $G$  contains a $k$-partite subgraph $H$ with $e(H) \ge \frac{k-1}{k}e(G)$.

Comment: I believe I have to first show that there is a k-partite subgraph such that $d_H(v) \ge \frac{k-1}{k}d_G(v), v \in V(G)$. Im not sure how to show this though.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439723/how-many-edges-in-a-tripartite-subgraph) question for $k=3$. The proof for an arbitrary $k$ is similar.